# Combine INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN with date selection

Tags: mysql, join

I have a complex query on my database where I want to join several tables.
Like this:

```
SELECT cad.artc, prod.sku, prod.product_id, prodclass.entity_id, prodclass.field_product_class_tid, tax.tid, substring(tax.name, 3), block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value, block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2
FROM _cadencier as cad
INNER JOIN commerce_product as prod
on prod.sku = cad.artc
AND cad.adrc = '000'
AND cad.relc = '000028'
INNER JOIN field_data_field_product_class as prodclass
on prodclass.entity_id = prod.product_id
INNER JOIN field_data_field_product_limited as limited
on limited.entity_id = prod.product_id
AND limited.field_product_limited_value = '0'
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data as tax
ON prodclass.field_product_class_tid = tax.tid
AND tax.language = 'nl'
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_product_blocktime_1 as block1
ON block1.entity_id = prod.product_id
GROUP BY tax.name, prod.title;
```

gives me below result:

[image]

I would like to exclude all products where today's date is NULL or not between the blocktime values. But in order to do so, I had to use `LEFT JOIN` rather then `INNER JOIN`. But when I try something like

```
WHERE block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value >= DATE(NOW())
AND block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2 <= DATE(NOW())
```

I end up with no results...
Do I join the wrong way?

Comment: How about changing it to `DATEDIFF(block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value,DATE(NOW())) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2,DATE(NOW())) <= 0` ?

Comment: Am I missing something; you appear to have a GROUP BY clause, but no aggregating functions.

Comment: @Strawberry, that's correct... But this is just a raw draft of a query. I'll transfer it to a Drupal query and it will aggregate within Drupal!

Comment: I don't know what that means, but then again - I don't even know what Drupal is ! :-(

Comment: I recommend you run the query _without_ a `GROUP BY` clause; because either it's collapsing rows (so the query isn't returning all the details rows, it's "hiding" values), or it's not collapsing rows, in which case it's not necessary. (Are you sure you didn't mean to specify `ORDER BY`? MySQL extension to ANSI SQL regarding GROUP BY is overly lenient, other RDBMS would throw an error with this statement.) Also, in regards to "today's date is NULL", I don't understand how we wouldn't have a non-NULL value for "today's date". The specification is unclear.

Comment: Did you try to apply a [mysql having condition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) (you have to search the page for further information)? Please note having is not optimal related to performance but for one time usage it should be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

ok.. sorry for misreading the question before...

thanks for pointing that out @michiel.

You can check it with:

```
WHERE (DATE(NOW()) NOT BETWEEN block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value AND block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2) OR block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to do the opposite. Exclude all product which are "blocked". Some products have a "block from" and "block two" value. If that value is set and today's date is between those two values, it shouldn't be listed...

Comment: I solved by slightly alter your answer `WHERE (DATE(NOW()) NOT BETWEEN block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value 
AND block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2) OR block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value IS NULL`, so if you edit your answer, I'll accept it as an answer since you came closest to the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Old answer: Misunderstanding of the question

To get the NULL values of the left joined table too, you've got to include your condition in the ON clause of the join. Using the condition in the WHERE clause changes your OUTER JOIN implicitly to an INNER one:

```
...
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_product_blocktime_1 as block1
ON block1.entity_id = prod.product_id
AND block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value >= DATE(NOW())
AND block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2 <= DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY tax.name, prod.title;
```

**Edited answer**

If you only want those rows with blockdates, then you've got to use an INNER JOIN.
Your `field_product_blocktime_1_value` seems to be the begin and `block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2` the end of the blocktime.

Because of that you want rows, where the current date is between

```
`field_product_blocktime_1_value`
```

and

```
block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2
```

You should swap your operators to get the desired result:

```
...
INNER JOIN field_data_field_product_blocktime_1 as block1
ON block1.entity_id = prod.product_id
WHERE 
    block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value <= DATE(NOW())
AND 
    block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2 >= DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY tax.name, prod.title;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure what you mean by this "on clause"... However, if I apply your suggestion, I just get all rows as return and all dates are set as NULL

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get the specified result (as I undestand it)

Modify your query to remove this:

```
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_product_blocktime_1 as block1
ON block1.entity_id = prod.product_id
WHERE block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value >= DATE(NOW())
AND block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2 <= DATE(NOW())
```

and replace it with this:

```
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM field_data_field_product_blocktime_1 block1
           WHERE block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value   <= DATE(NOW())
             AND block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2  >= DATE(NOW()) 
             AND block1.entity_id = prod.product_id
       )
```

Note that what we want find is rows in the `block1` table where the current date is between the two column values, for a given product_id. If we find a "matching" row then we want to exclude the row from being returned.

To do the equivalent using an anti-join pattern, we could replace that with something like this:

```
  LEFT
  JOIN field_data_field_product_blocktime_1 block1
    ON block1.entity_id = prod.product_id
   AND block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value  <= DATE(NOW())
   AND block1.field_product_blocktime_1_value2 >= DATE(NOW()) 
 WHERE block1.entity_id IS NULL
```

Again, we're looking for a matching row in `block1` (just like we did with the `NOT EXISTS` predicate . The "trick" is in the `WHERE` clause, we use a predicate that exclude all rows that had a match, by testing a column that we know will be non-NULL if we found a match.

Also, at least for debugging, remove the `GROUP BY` clause, and add an `ORDER BY` clause.

That `GROUP BY` clause is either collapsing rows, and hiding values, or it's not collapsing any rows, in which case it may not be necessary.

I suspect you mean to use an `ORDER BY` clause, rather than `GROUP BY` clause, the two are *quite* different. (The MySQL extension to the ANSI standard for `GROUP BY` is overly lenient; the query with a `GROUP BY` would throw an error in other RDBMS.) That's just a suspicion; worth mentioning, just in case you hadn't considered that.